# Sitecore 7 MVC create partial rendering from controller using presentation details of the item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sitecore

Is there some way in Sitecore 7 when using MVC to create a controller which can return a PartialView result using the rendering defined on the item (or its template standard values), without having to set up Layout and Renderings for that item?

I can see how to do this using custom template fields, but this seems like a hacky way of doing things.  Is there a better way to achieve the following:

```
public PartialViewResult MyAction(string someParameter)
{
    Item selectedItem;
    //some code here to retrieve sitecore item based on the value of someParameter

    var cshtmlFilePath = selectedItem["MyCustomField"];

    return PartialView(cshtmlFilePath, selectedItem);
}
```

FYI my cshtml could be something really simple like:

```
@model Sitecore.Data.Items.Item
<div>
    <h3>
        @Html.Sitecore().Field("Title", Model)
    </h3>
    <div>
        @Html.Sitecore().Field("Content", Model)
    </div>
</div>
```

While the approach above will work, I don't like it because there is not a proper interface for assigning the rendering to the item's template's standard values.  I could easily define my own presentation template which has a single 'Path' field, then create items somewhere under `sitecore/layout/Renderings' then reference that item in a link field of my content item, but it just seems like that should be doable out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the intent here, so this may only be a partial answer, but seeing as you want to render an item based on layout information contained within the item itself, would Item Renderings be able to help?

Here's the info: http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/06/MVC-Item-Renderings-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

I realize returning a partial view would be a little more flexible than the Item Rendering route, but in the normal scenario (i.e. adding a callout to a page) it seems like this method might work.

Comment: I was hoping to return a partial view, as this lets me embed that control either by writing @Html.Action("Controller", "MyAction", new {someParameter="something"}) or to call the controller client-side via an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to simply assign a layout (which references a cshtml file) to the item, then use `item.Visualization` to get the file path to the layout assigned to the item and use that layout's cshtml file in the call to `PartialView`.

```
public PartialViewResult MyAction(string contentItem)
{
    Item selectedItem;
    //retrieve sitecore item
    string layoutPath = selectedItem.Visualization.Layout.FilePath;
    return PartialView(layoutPath, modalContentItem);
}
```